# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException al mostrar los datos de una tabla con AbstractTableModel (java)

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Tengo un programa en java con una clase que me genera una tabla que extiende de `AbstractTableModel`:

```
class MTPUsuariosConectados extends AbstractTableModel{
    private static Vector nicks = new Vector();
    
    public MTPUsuariosConectados(){
        nicks.addElement(Cliente.getUsuarioConectado());
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        int numFilas = Cliente.getNumJugadoresInt();
        return numFilas;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        
        if(columnIndex == 0){
               return "#" + (String) nicks.elementAt(rowIndex * getColumnCount());
        }
        
        if(columnIndex == 1){
            return "Conectado";
        }
        
        return "";
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int i){
        if(i == 0){
            return "Nick";
        }
        
        if(i == 1){
            return "Estado";
        }
        
        return "";
    }
    
}
```

La idea es que cada vez que se añade un jugador en el sistema se guarde el número total de jugadores como el número de filas de la tabla, tal y como indico en `getRowCount()` (he hecho unas comprobaciones y el método `Cliente.getNumJugadoresInt();` devuelve correctamente el número de jugadores). Al llamar a la tabla cuando hay un jugador en el sistema se muestra correctamente dicho jugador (y por tanto la tabla tiene una fila), como se muestra en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando llamo a esta tabla y hay más de un jugador en el sistema (por ejemplo, 2 jugadores) debería devolver dos filas y en la primera columna de ellas sus nombres (en la segunda aperecería el String "Conectado"). El problema es que esto no ocurre y en su lugar se me muestra una `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
    at practica.pkgfinal.mtpa.MTPUsuariosConectados.getValueAt(TablaPersonalizada.java:551)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
```

La línea 551 de `TablaPersonalizada` es, precisamente, la del método `getValueAt`:

`return "#" + (String) nicks.elementAt(rowIndex * getColumnCount());`

Esta es mi clase `TablaPersonalizada`, la cual necesito usar para llamar a `MTPUsuariosConectados`:

```
public class TablaPersonalizada extends JDialog{
    private static JTable tablaUsuariosConectados = null;
    private static TableModel modeloUsuariosConectados = null;
    
    public TablaPersonalizada(){
        modeloUsuariosConectados = new MTPUsuariosConectados();
        tablaUsuariosConectados = new JTable(modeloUsuariosConectados);

        add(new JScrollPane(tablaUsuariosConectados));

        tablaUsuariosConectados.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        tablaUsuariosConectados.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        tablaUsuariosConectados.setEnabled(false);
        tablaUsuariosConectados.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para evitar este error y que se muestren correctamente los jugadores en la tabla cuando son dos o más?

Comment: Lo que tienes en *nicks* no son dos jugadores, es solo un elemento "cliente.getUsuarioConectado()". ¿Y por qué es *nicks* un atributo *static*?

Comment: @SJuan76 nicks es un atributo static porque lo uso en otra clase, la cual no muestro aquí, que necesita su valor sin crear una instancia de la clase que lo contiene